# How to disable extra options of 2nd selectbox based on value selected in 1st selectbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having 2 select box, code below.

Parent Selectbox

```
<select name="user_type" id="user_type">
    <option value="">Please Choose An Option</option>
    <option value="PRIVATE OWNER">PRIVATE OWNER</option>
    <option value="TRADER">TRADER</option>
</select>
```

Child Selectbox

```
<select name="package_type" id="package_type">
    <option value="">Please Choose An Option</option>
    <option value="SINGLE ENTRY">SINGLE ENTRY</option>
    <option value="FEATURED ENTRY">FEATURED ENTRY</option>
    <option value="STANDARD">STANDARD</option>
    <option value="ULTIMATE">ULTIMATE</option>
</select>
```

I want if private owner is selected from the parent selectbox then only SINGLE ENTRY and FEATURED ENTRY SHOULD SHOW UP and rest of them are removed or deleted using jquery.

I dont have any clue about how to achieve this.

Below is my jquery code, it doesnt include the code for the logic about what I am asking as I have no idea how to dynamically add or remove  tags.

Also please exclude the php part in below code as it my own logic to fetch the values from session and database and provide them to jquery variables etc.

Please let me know how can I achieve this thing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php
// Pre Populate User From Session
$user_type = $session->getSession("packages_user_type");
if ($user_type != "TRADER")
{
?>
    $('#package_type_container, #slots_container, #notes_ultimate').hide();
<?
}
?>
    $('#user_type').change(function()
    {
        var user_type = $(this).val();
        if(user_type == "TRADER")
        {
            $('#package_type_container').slideDown().show();
            $('#slots_container').slideDown().show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#package_type").find("option:selected").removeAttr('selected');
            $('#package_type_container').slideUp();
            $('#slots_container').slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('#package_type').change(function()
    {
        var package_type = $(this).val();
        if(package_type == "SINGLE ENTRY")
        {
            $('#slots').val('1').attr('readonly', true);
            $('#cost').val('').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
        else if(package_type == "FEATURED ENTRY")
        {
            $('#slots').val('1').attr('readonly', true);
            $('#cost').val('').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
        else if (package_type == "ULTIMATE")
        {
            $('#notes_ultimate').slideDown().show();
            $('#slots').val('').removeAttr('readonly');
            $('#cost').val('0').attr('readonly', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#notes_ultimate').hide();
            $('#slots').val('').removeAttr('readonly');
            $('#cost').val('').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove the options then appending the relevant options afterwards

```
var $popts = $('#package_type option'); // store all available options
var sel = {
    "default": $popts.eq(0), 
    "PRIVATE OWNER": $popts.slice(1,3), // available values for PRIVATE OWNER
    "TRADER": $popts.slice(1) // available values for TRADER
};

$('#user_type').change(function(){
    // detach all options
    $('#package_type option').detach();
    // if value is '' then append the default - else append the correct options
    $('#package_type').append(this.value == '' ? sel['default'] : sel[this.value]);    
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/zNqmZ/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest explicitly defining a relation in the HTML between the options that indicates what `option`s in the second `select` should be available in response to the chosen `option` (using a custom `data-*` attribute) from the first, so I'd use something like the following:

HTML:

```
<select name="user_type" id="user_type">
    <option value="">Please Choose An Option</option>
    <option value="private owner">private owner</option>
    <option value="trader">trader</option>
</select>

<select name="package_type" id="package_type">
    <option value="">Please Choose An Option</option>
    <option value="single entry" data-relatesTo="privateOwner trader">single entry</option>
    <option value="featured entry" data-relatesTo="privateOwner trader">featured entry</option>
    <option value="standard" data-relatesTo="trader">standard</option>
    <option value="ultimate" data-relatesTo="trader">ultimate</option>
</select>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#user_type').change(
    function() {
        // camel-cases the value of the selected option
        var v = $(this).val().replace(/\s+(\w)/, function(a) {
            return a.replace(/(^\s+)/, '').toUpperCase();
        });
        // finds all disabled options and un-disables/enables them
        $('#package_type option:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
        // selects all options in the second select
        $('#package_type option').filter(

        function() {
            // caches the current $(this) object, since we might use it more than once
            var that = $(this);
            // returns the current $(this) if it has a value that's not an empty string
            // AND
            // if the camel-cased value (from above) is *not* found in the
            // data-relatesTo attribute
            return that.val() !== '' && that.attr('data-relatesTo').indexOf(v) === -1;
        }).prop('disabled', true);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/avCja/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`String.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`:disabled` selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks it helped me to some extent